# Поможете дописать авто-редирект при успешной оплате?

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

В данный момент при любом статусе оплаты или ее стадии осуществляется редирект на нужную страницу и все ок, но только при клике на "вернуться в магазин". А нужно чтобы если оплата была успешной, то делать авто-редирект. Не могу пока догнать как это сделать, ценю любую помощь.

```
<?php session_start();

    // Включаем отображение ошибок
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // error_reporting(-1);

    // Сохраняем форму в куки
    setcookie('user_email', ''. $_POST['email'] .'', time()+2678400, '/');
    setcookie('user_tell', ''. $_POST['tell'] .'', time()+2678400, '/');
    setcookie('user_name', ''. $_POST['name'] .'', time()+2678400, '/');

    // Генерация ссылки
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/yandex-checkout/autoload.php';

    use YandexCheckout\Client;

    $client = new Client();
        $client->setAuth('***', '***');

        $payment = $client->createPayment(
            array(
                'amount' => array(
                    'value' => 1.0,
                    'currency' => 'RUB',
                ),
                'confirmation' => array(
                    'type' => 'redirect',
                    'return_url' => 'https://mysite.ru/payment-page-success.html'
                ),
                'capture' => true,
                'description' => 'Новая покупка'
        ),
        uniqid('', true)
        );


$r_url = 'https://mysite.ru/payment-page-success.html';

      if(isset($payment['confirmation']['confirmation_url'])){
        setcookie('user_payment_id', ''. $payment['id'] .'', time()+2678400, '/');
        $return = ['success' => $payment['confirmation']['confirmation_url']];
      } else {
        $return = ['error' => 'Ссылка для оплаты не создана'];
      }

      echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: а где у вас здесь происходит редирект то?

Comment: @Alpha Его как я понял и нет полностью, вообще я сделал все по оф инструкции кассы. Вот редирект там не написан нифига. Извиняюсь за такой тупой вопрос, созданный мною. Не поможете написать редирект? Или дать ссылки на то, где могу почитать и сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было вмешательство менеджера яндекса, потратил столько сил и времени.

@V.March то, что для авто редиректа нужно было вмешательство с их стороны.

Видимо они вставили мою ссылку куда должна касса редиректить и расскоментировали строку)))

Единственный момент - в создании платежа должно быть это

```
'confirmation' => array(
    'type' => 'redirect',
    'return_url' => 'https://mysite.ru/payment-page-success.html'
),
```

Comment: Так что менеджер то сказал? Как помог?

Comment: @V.March то, что для авто редиректа нужно было вмешательство с их стороны. Видимо они вставили мою ссылку куда должна касса редиректить и расскоментировали строку))) Единственный момент - в создании платежа должно быть это 'confirmation' => array(
                    'type' => 'redirect',
                    'return_url' => 'https://mysite.ru/payment-page-success.html'
                ),

Comment: @МайклМиллер добавьте лучше эту информацию в ответ. Т.к. в текушем виде он мало кому поможет =\

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($payment['confirmation']['confirmation_url'])){
    setcookie('user_payment_id', ''. $payment['id'] .'', time()+2678400, '/');
    $return = ['success' => $payment['confirmation']['confirmation_url']];
    header("Location: $return_url");
    exit;
}
```

Не забудьте объявить переменную `$return_url`;

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но когд добавил Вашу строчку редиректа и объявил переменную, то касса не открывается. Что-то не так. Я уже сам запутался и не уверен, что правильно задал вопрос. Если кликнуть на "вернуться в магазин" при любом статусе оплаты или ее стадии, то редирект осуществится, но авторедирект при успешной оплаты не осуществляется. Я имел в виду именно авторедирект. Извиняюсь если не правильно поставил вопрос.

Comment: @МайклМиллер Весь редирект сводится к строчке кода `header("Location: $return_url;  exit;")`. Вам нужно разобраться в коде, где именно выполняется проверка на успешную оплату. Как я понимаю `код который Вы указали выше` лишь создаёт ссылку для подтверждения оплаты. Нужно разобраться с YandexAPI.